# Row inside a list view is not shown

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Row which contains some containers as children like this:

```
Row(
    children: addEntities(),
),
```

where addEntities return a list of containers...

Now i want to scroll that row horizontally .. so i tried this:

```
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
    Row(
           children: addEntities(),
       ),
    ],
),
```

but this now displays nothing and return this error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
flutter: Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
flutter: Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a horizontal
flutter: viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation
flutter: typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
flutter: If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
flutter: there will always be enough horizontal space for the children. In this case, consider using a Row
flutter: instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
flutter: the width of the viewport to the sum of the widths of its children.
```

I tried alot of options from this question: [Flutter Listview Scrollable Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762079/flutter-listview-scrollable-row)

But none worked ...

How to solve this problem? I want the row to scroll horizontally?

my full code:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
},
child: new Row(
children: <Widget>[

entitiesFilter.isEmpty
     ? Text( uiLabels['filterSearchOrg'] [globals.currentLang],
       style: TextStyle( fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp( fontSize['15-2'] [globals.platform]),
      ),
    )
  : SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: addEntities(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Spacer(),
  new Icon(
     CustomFont.arrow_bottom_1,
     size: 7.0,
     color: Color(0xffBAB9BD),
   ),
  ],
 ),
),
```

Comment: Wrap that with SingleChildScrollVieew instead of ListView

Comment: @salihguler i did .. but was not scrollable

Comment: @salihguler i will get this error: The following message was thrown during layout A RenderFlex overflowed by 38 pixels on the right. and it will not scroll

Comment: Wait, you want the row to scroll?

Comment: @RémiRousselet yes

Comment: That's a whole new problem. You'll want to use `CustomScrollView` instead of `ListView`

Comment: @RémiRousselet how? can you please give me an example

Comment: That completely depends on what UI you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest to make a new question with a title similar to "How to do nested scroll in Flutter?". And include a visual example of the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

On `Row`, set `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` or wrap it into an `IntrinsicWidth` widget.

By default, `Row` fill the horizontal space, which conflicts with `ListView` in horizontal mode. `ListView` will use the horizontal size of its children to determine if it's scrollable or not.

Comment: I just posted the full widget tree.. i tried to add                                                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
to the row as you suggested .. but i nothing appear now!

Comment: Wrap Row to ```SizebBox```, and give some height and width.